# error building mongodb from source

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build mongod from source pulled from their master branch on their github repo but almost immediately get an error when I run `scons all` per [these instructions](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source):

```
IndexError: list index out of range:
  File "/home/sdause/Downloads/mongo-master/SConstruct", line 2580:
    env.SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='$BUILD_DIR', duplicate=False)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "/home/sdause/Downloads/mongo-master/src/SConscript", line 14:
    ] + module_sconscripts
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "/home/sdause/Downloads/mongo-master/src/mongo/SConscript", line 40:
    'util',
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "/home/sdause/Downloads/mongo-master/src/mongo/installer/SConscript", line 7:
    'msi',
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 546:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 260:
    exec _file_ in call_stack[-1].globals
  File "/home/sdause/Downloads/mongo-master/src/mongo/installer/msi/SConscript", line 89:
    major_version = "%s.%s" % (mv[0], mv[1])
```

Similar errors are printed when I run `scons mongo`.

Comment: I'm trying to debug something in their source code.  I'm having a similar problem to what's described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iUj2egU7vhE

Answer (score 5):

This might help you out

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/noH__CkufmU/1MjlHo5cCAAJ

When you download the zip file from github that way, it doesn't give you the repository metadata, which is what the build system uses to derive a version number.

If you want to build from source, I recommend either:

- Making a complete git clone of the repository and checking out the version you are interested in building, or
- Downloading a source archive, which will contain a pre-interpolated version number.

Finally, if neither of the above is an option for you, you can explicitly pass the version and git hash that you want to set for the build by passing the SCons Variables MONGO_VERSION and MONGO_GITHASH to your SCons invocation:

```
scons MONGO_VERSION=x.y.z MONGO_GITHASH=none ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't need GITHASH but did need to set MONGO_VERSION  to actual number, not tag number, e.g. 3.4.4 not r3.4.4